# Get nth element if it doesn't contain a class

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to get 6th `<td>` tag as long as it doesn't contain a class. Sometimes there are 7 elements and sometimes 6. The structure is either like this

```
<tr>
   <td class ="name">XXX</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>10</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td class="final">24</td>
</tr>
```

Or

```
<tr>
   <td class ="name">XXX</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>10</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td class="final">18</td>
</tr>
```

I want to either return the 6 if it exists (first example) or blank if it doesn't (second example).

I've tried

```
/tr[1]/td[5 And not(@class)]
```

but that appears to return everything without a class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Value "final" of attribute "class" has no closing quote

2) Xpath counts position from the 1

```
/tr[1]/td[position()=6 and not(@class)]
```

Comment: Thanks that appears to work. The missing quote was just a typo. This also appears to work 
/tr[1][count(td)=7]/td[6]